# iterate which function over vector of numbers

Tags: r

I have two vectors of numbers. I would like to find the first position in the larger vector that is greater than each of the elements in the smaller vector. This is achievable with the which function and a loop but I was hoping to achieve this with one simple line of code.

example

```
small_vector <- c(555.8, 457.4, 392.3, 294.24, 228.80, 163.44, 98.08)

large_vector <- c(20.1, 14.8, 23.3, 38.1, 40.2, 48.7, 48.7 , 54.0 ,60.5 ,64.6 , 85.8, 93.1, 99.5, 115.4, 133.4, 158.8, 206.4, 289.1, 353.7, 428.9, 558.0, 661.8)

which.max(small_vector <= large_vector)
```

I would like the return to be something like:

```
[1] 21 21 20 19 18 17 13
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also use `outer` with `max.col`:

```
max.col(outer(small_vector, large_vector, '<='), 'first')
[1] 21 21 20 19 18 17 13
```

EDIT:

the solutions above are not feasible when the vectors are large. Hence the need for edit. THE feasible solution will be using the data.table `frank` as it is faster than `rank` from base R according to the documentation:

```
library(data.table)
n <- seq_along(small_vector)
x <- frank(c(small_vector, large_vector), ties.method = 'first')[n]
y <- frank(small_vector, ties.method = 'first') - 1
x - y
[1] 21 21 20 19 18 17 13
```

benchmarking the above:

```
f_sapply <-  function(){
  sapply(small_vector, function(S) which.max(S <= large_vector))
}

f_datatable_rank <- function(){
  n <- seq_along(small_vector)
  x <- frank(c(small_vector, large_vector), ties.method = 'first')[n]
  y <- frank(small_vector, ties.method = 'first') - 1
  x - y
}

f_baseR_rank <- function(){
  n <- seq_along(small_vector)
  x <- rank(c(small_vector, large_vector), ties.method = 'first')[n]
  y <- rank(small_vector, ties.method = 'first') - 1
  x - y
}

f_outer <- function(){
  max.col(outer(small_vector, large_vector, '<='), 'first')
}


a <- microbenchmark(f_sapply(), f_outer(), f_baseR_rank(), f_datatable_rank(),
                    times = 10,
                    check = 'equal')
Unit: microseconds
               expr        min         lq        mean     median         uq        max neval
         f_sapply()  19654.007  21044.502  27836.2294  30436.816  31303.824  32598.046    10
          f_outer() 188230.644 194679.142 197723.3888 196696.690 199794.034 210718.518    10
     f_baseR_rank()    451.830    469.334    544.6752    540.263    550.291    792.433    10
 f_datatable_rank()   1081.983   1335.431   1513.4631   1509.925   1772.672   1834.301    10
```

If you increase the vectors, the benchmark will fail because of the `outer` and `sapply` but `rank` will work

Comment: Notice that `large_vector` is not ordered (in particular, the first element), which means the `order` and `rank`/`frank` approaches won't work. For example, add `19` to the end of `small_vector`. The OP doesn't mention any assumptions about ordering.

Comment: @jblood94 i see. I dont know why i quickly thought of the python `np.searchsorted` function and was trying to implement it in R. in particular the example given, if one was to run `np.searchsorted(large_vector, small_vector)` you will get the posted results. thought of using `rank` function. Well i guess in that case, the `max.col` function will work

Comment: I spoke too soon. The `order`/`rank`/`frank` methods work great after applying `cummax` to `large_vector`. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

```r
sapply(small_vector, function(S) which.max(S <= large_vector))
# [1] 21 21 20 19 18 17 13
```

Answer (score 1):

This should scale well with larger vectors:

```
(which(order(c(small_vector, cummax(large_vector))) <= length(small_vector)) - 0:(length(small_vector) - 1))[order[rank(small_vector)] 

#> [1] 21 21 20 19 18 17 13
```

Some benchmarking:

```
set.seed(42)
library(data.table)
small_vector <- runif(700)
large_vector <- runif(2200)
max(small_vector) > max(large_vector)
#> [1] FALSE

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(sapply = sapply(small_vector, function(S) which.max(S <= large_vector)),
                               outer = max.col(outer(small_vector, large_vector, '<='), 'first'),
                               rank = rank(c(small_vector, cummax(large_vector)), ties.method = 'first')[seq_along(small_vector)] - rank(small_vector, ties.method = 'first') + 1L,
                               frank = frank(c(small_vector, cummax(large_vector)), ties.method = 'first')[seq_along(small_vector)] - frank(small_vector, ties.method = 'first') + 1L,
                               order = (which(order(c(small_vector, cummax(large_vector))) <= length(small_vector)) - 0:(length(small_vector) - 1))[rank(small_vector)],
                               check = ifelse(max(small_vector) > max(large_vector), NULL, "equal"))
#> Unit: microseconds
#>    expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
#>  sapply  5340.6  5946.35  8407.405  7200.35  9659.95  48621.4   100
#>   outer 41873.3 48768.95 55574.427 51792.85 57398.10 102633.4   100
#>    rank   437.6   507.95   623.041   574.25   691.80   1427.5   100
#>   frank  1225.8  1627.65  1841.819  1820.30  2044.00   3122.2   100
#>   order   338.1   398.15   521.774   439.25   515.45   6185.3   100
```

A side note: I noticed that the `sapply` and `outer` solutions incorrectly return `1` for elements in `small_vector` that are larger than all elements in `large_vector`, whereas the `rank`/`order` solutions will return `1 + length(large_vector)` (which is straightforward to interpret correctly). Of course, if it's not a possibility, all approaches in the benchmark return the same result.

Comment: Please read the question again. The solution `sapply` is the logic of the question. If your solution does not match the output of `sapply` given by r2evans, then it does not solve the problem. The question asks to obtain the index in the large vector, wereby its greater than ALL elements in small vector. The reason why its giving 1 is because the very first element of large vector is greater than the value of small vector. And that should be the correct answer.

Comment: Also the `rank` function should be exactly as `frank` just drop the `f`. And when doing benchmark. Always include `check = 'equal'` to ensure that the functions produce same results. Otherwise we will be comparing two different functions

Comment: @Onyambu Try adding `19, 700` to the end of `small_vector`. They both return `1` for the `sapply` solution. The reason is because `small_vector[9] <= large_vector` becomes a vector of all `FALSE`. `which.max` returns `1` because the maximum value of a vector of all `FALSE` is first encountered at position 1. The results of the benchmark are not all equal because it happens that `max(small_vector) > max(large_vector)` with a seed of `3`.

Comment: @Onyambu I updated the benchmark in the answer with a different seed that results in `max(small_vector) <= max(large_vector)`. It passes `check = "equal"`.